Are two Hilbert-Schmidt operators pointwise equal iff the norm of their difference is zero?
Let $HS(H_1, H_2)$ be the Hilbert space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $H_1 \to H_2$. For $A, B \in HS(H_1, H_2)$ do we have pointwise equality $A = B$ (i.e. $Ax = Bx$ for all $x$) if and only if $\Vert A - B \Vert_{HS(H_1, H_2)} = 0$?
I think this should follow straightforwardly from the fact that in arbitrary Hilbert Spaces we have $\langle c, c \rangle = 0$ iff $c = 0$, and by setting $c = A - B$. But I am getting myself confused with almost everywhere equality. Does anything change if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces?
A good reference for this would be very helpful!

The answers below are good, but I want to add a caveat. You can talk about pointwise behavior of some $L^2$ spaces that have more structure such as holomorphic $L^2$ spaces like the Segal-Bargmann space.

By definition of a norm, if $\|x-y\| = 0$ one must have $x=y$.

Thanks, if we instead consider $L^2$ space, the norm here results in almost everywhere equality correct? i.e. $x$ and $y$ could differ on sets of measure zero. Do we have pointwise equality in my question?

The point is that if the norm of the difference between two operators is zero, the two operators are the same and we do have pointwise equality. In L^2 and other spaces of integrable functions we always think in terms of classes of equivalence, two functions that only differ in a set with measure zero are actually the same function in $L^2$.

Technically, $L^2$ spaces are spaces of equivalence classes of functions under equality a.e., not functions, so two functions that are equal almost everywhere are the same member of $L^2$.  Similarly, two Hilbert-Schmidt kernels that are equal almost everywhere produce the same Hilbert-Schmidt operator.
